# Awarding bounty after it expires

Tags: support

I placed a bounty on [someone else's question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/10836/using-pathfinders-variant-wounds-and-vigor-rules), because I was interested in the answer, and it didn't seem to be getting attention.  It expired unawarded, because no one answered the question.  Today, someone did, and the answer is very much what I was looking for.  Is there a way to award that bounty to the answerer.  Or is it just gone?

Answer (score 5):

It appears the answer is no, it's gone.

From the [Meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/151694)

> What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?
>
> What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?
>
> What is automatic awarding?
>
> Twenty-four hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, an eligible answer can be automatically awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be eligible for automatic awarding are as follows:
>
> - The answer must be given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - If two or more eligible answers have the same score, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> **If no answers meet these criteria, the bounty ends without it being awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.**

Comment: Thanks for the response; I figured that might be the case, but I couldn't find an answer for that exact problem over on the Meta FAQ other than that reference, and I wasn't sure if that was saying what I thought it was saying.

Comment: can we change this behavior, or is it hardcoded in the site?